# Azure AppService not mapping in Asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I just created an App Service on Azure for hosting my API.

I am using the following for routing my controllers

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints
                .MapControllers();
        });
```

And it is working fine when running on my developer machine both from Visual Studio and from Docker.

I am using .NET Core 3.1 and my App Service is running on Linux

I hope someone in here can guide me in the right direction.
Or give me some ideas of how to approve the debugging, as I am out of ideas.

I have created my own Authorization, and I can see in the log, that it is called correctly and works.

The response I retrieve from the request is just

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
  "title": "Not Found",
  "status": 404,
  "traceId": "00-f60614731b520445998f179ab864fca9-51da7f01774d2144-00"
}
```

Comment: Have you try to use remote debugging ?

Comment: Please double check the URL and make sure it can be matched to existing routing(s) that you configure with [attribute route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis).

Comment: @JasonPan - How to do that?